# How do I generate a string of asterisks with specified length?

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010

How would I generate a string of asterisks of specified length (so I could use it alongside the .Length property of an array item)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that using the `String(Char, Int32)` constructor overload of `System.String`.

> Initializes a new instance of the String class to the value indicated
>   by a specified Unicode character repeated a specified number of times.

You can use the constructor like this:

```
Dim mystr As String = New String("*"c, array.Length)
```

---

There are many more [constructor overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for `System.String`.

Comment: @c3ntury If this answer helped you and solved your problem, you should accept it as the answer ;).

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim myString As String = ""
myString = myString.padLeft(length, "*")
```